# Kann man ein Vergehen begehen?

Tags: meaning, standard-german

Ich möchte ganz einfach wissen, ob diese Redewendung/dieser Satz etwas auf Deutsch bedeutet, ob sie/er einen Sinn hat.
Und was wäre diese Bedeutung?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Willkommen in German SE. Für diese Art von Fragen kann man das [DWDS-Wortprofil](https://www.dwds.de/wp/Vergehen) verwenden. Einige Beispiele: *Die drei haben keine Vergehen auf britischem Boden begangen.* (Der Tagesspiegel, 11.03.2004) *Die Wiedereingliederung von Menschen, die ein Vergehen oder Verbrechen begangen haben, in die Gesellschaft verlangt zweierlei: ...* (Die Zeit, 13.03.1970, Nr. 11)

Answer (score 4):

Ja, man kann ein Vergehen begehen.

Ein Satz wie "Ich habe ein Vergehen begangen" heißt dann soviel wie "Ich habe das getan" in Hinblick auf was-immer das konkrete Vergehen war.

Das klingt aber wegen der Doppelung etwas schräg. Deshalb würde man es meist etwas anders formulieren indem man das das Vergehen konkret benennt wie bspw. Betrug oder Nötigung.

NB: [Vergehen](https://www.anwalt.org/vergehen/#Vergehen_oder_Verbrechen_Welcher_Unterschied_besteht) ist in der Juristerei ein fester Begriff, der minder schwere Straftaten beschreibt, die noch kein Verbrechen sind.

Comment: Das Wort "Vergehen" wird auch außerhalb des Strafrechts verwendet, z.B. in den [Fußballregeln](https://www.weltfussball.de/fussballregeln/12/1/). Man findet dort sogar die schöne Passage "... dass auch Spieler, die verschiedene **Vergehen begehen**, wegen wiederholten Verstoßens gegen die Spielregeln verwarnt werden müssen."

Comment: Klar, das wird auch ganz normal genutzt. Ach wie schön, das in den Fußball - Regeln zu finden